# Direction of forces when calculating net force with buoyancy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, buoyancy

Given an object attach to spring scales showing the mass of the objest is `0.324KG`.
We then **dip** the object in the water and the scales shows `0.2KG`.
So we can sum the forces and find $\rho'$.
Now this is where I get confused which way I should sum the forces:
$$
1.\hspace{8pt}\sum F_y = W - Buoyancy = 0.324g - V\rho g = 0.2g
$$
Or
$$
2.\hspace{8pt}\sum F_y = Buoyancy - W = V\rho g - 0.324g = 0.2g
$$
Because each equation gives different values for $\rho'$,
and nothing indicates if $W > Buoyancy$ or $Buoyancy > W$, because the question only states that we **dip** the object in the water and get a different scaling.

Comment: What is $\rho'$? There is no such symbol in your equations.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on you. You can chose upwards to be the positive direction, or downwards to be the positive direction. But often the positive direction is taken to be the positive y-axis.

It also appears that you are using the equations incorrectly. You are writing the equations as if there is a net acceleration on the system, yet there is not $ma_{net}$ on the RHS of the equations. Instead you have an additional weight term $mg$ on the RHS which is not needed since this is included in the $W = mg$ term.

If you have a spring-mass system, the force is given by [Hooke's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)

$$F = -kx$$

where you can see that the direction of the force is opposite to the direction of the displacement. When the object is in the water, and taking upwards as the positive axis, then

$$kx + \rho Vg - mg = 0$$

where the weight force $W=mg$. And if you take downwards to be the positive axis, then

$$mg - kx - \rho Vg = 0$$

Either way, you will still get the same answer for the density $\rho$.

EDIT: In the comments you seem to suggest that there is a net acceleration on the mass, which would make sense looking at your equations - but why there is a $g$ for acceleration seems to be a mistake. If this acceleration is $a$ and you also commented that the Hooke's law force is not needed (?) then your equations should be written

$$\rho Vg - mg = ma$$

or

$$mg - \rho Vg  = -ma$$

Once again, either way you will get a consistent answer for $\rho$.

**Why you would not include the restoring force component makes no sense**.

Including the restoring force **and** the net acceleration then

$$kx + \rho Vg - mg = ma_{net}$$

or

$$mg - kx - \rho Vg = -ma_{net}$$

Al of these equations can be deduced from Newton's second law which states that the sum of **all the forces** on a system, or the **net force** is given by

$$\sum_i \vec F_i = \vec F_1 + \vec F_2 + \vec F_3 +...+ \vec F_n = m \vec a_{net} $$

where $\vec a_{net}$ is the **net acceleration** of the system.

Comment: Sorry nothing related to Hooke's Law regarding this question. The answer from the book does `W - Buoyancy = 0.2g` and if I do `Buoyancy - W = 0.2g` I obviously get a different answer so I wonder why because as you've stated I really thought it depends on what I choose as the positive direction and what not but it seems I get different result plugging the numbers.

Comment: There is something wrong with that. The mass is attached to a spring isn't it? Well, if yo do it your way, then if you have W -  B = 0.2g, then B - W = -0.2g. You will get the same answer either way. But it is incorrect to do it that way since you have weight on both sides.

Comment: It's a homework question that Hooke's law wasn't introduced just yet, same as we don't take into account wind or any other external forces, the use of scales is just to indicate that we've scaled the object before dipping it into the water and also scaling it while it's in the water somehow :)
Anyway why would you do B - W = -0.2g? I mean at first I did B - W = 0.2g, so what gave you the knowledge to add a minus before the 0.2g part if you go this way?

Comment: Let me tell you why this makes no sense. The weight force W = mg. Right? Now you have a buoyant force which acts opposite to the weight force. So W - B = 0 because the object is not moving. Now why would you add an additional weight term like W - B = mg ???? I don't know exactly what you are doing, but what you have presented makes no sense.

Comment: I have not written once the object is not moving

Comment: So there is an additional acceleration? The object is accelerating in the water? Then why would you type mg and not ma where a is the acceleration? Can you see how it does not make sense? You need to edit your question to reflect this (if it is true, and I don't think it is - you have made a mistake).

Comment: I have not.The question simply state a scale reading before dipping the object in the water and after dipping it in the water, nothing less nothing more.The answer according to my book is by doing `W - B = 0.2g` I didn't realize you can do `B - W = -0.2g` and this is why I asked you, what gives one the intuition about adding a minus sign to the 0.2g part if deciding to do `B - W` instead, as I'm not 100% sure on this. I assume that this is because the scales show positive term and we chose g as accelerating downwards with the direction of `W` but I'm unsure of it and would prefer clarification

Comment: Yes. Now you have it. All forces in a particular direction should have the same sign. Whether it is + or - is up to you. **You** choose the positive direction and be consistent, and you will always get the right answer. Please read my answer again to make sure, and ask another question if you are confused about directions. Thanks..